# Carry artifacts of Gitlab pages between pipelines/jobs

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pages

I am trying to generate test reports via pipeline. Html is generated and I am able to access the Gitlab page for the same. However the issue arises if a  new pipeline (or even if a job) is triggered, test report is generated and the previous one gives 404 error.
(URLs are different)

i.e for eg: example.gitlab.io/project/{CI_PIPELINE_ID}/
or {CI_JOB_ID}

The use case is that this does not give me an option to compare between test reports.

A solution was to cache the public folder and then I am able to access different versions of the test in their respective URLs.

However I am new to this and I am not sure if that is correct for I have to clear the cache manually which I believe is only available to the maintainers and owners of the project.

**Is there any other way to preserve the Gitlab pages from the previous pipelines?**

P.S: I am new to this

Edit: Adding a sample gitlab-ci.yml file for reference:

```
stages:
  - build

pages:
  image: cypress/base:10
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npx cypress run
  after_script:
    # Generate report using mochaswesome-merge 
    # Combine different json files into single json file
    - npx mochawesome-merge cypress/reporters/json/*.json > cypress/reporters/output.json
    # Generate html from the json file using marge. Eache new html is created inside a new folder based on timeline. 
    - npx marge cypress/reporters/output.json -f cypress/reporters/$(date +"%Y%m%d-%Ih%Mm") -o ./ --inline
    # Make a public folder for the gitlab page to be created
    - mkdir -p public
    - mkdir -p public/$(date +"%Y%m%d-%Ih%Mm")/
    # Moving the contents of the report folder inside a public under the same folder name as the report
    - mv cypress/reporters/* public/$(date +"%Y%m%d-%Ih%Mm")/
    #Creating an index html that will have the file listing of all the generated reports 
    - cd public
    - echo "<html><body><h1>File listing:</h1>" > ./index.html
    - find -iname '*.html' -execdir echo "<a href='{}'>{}</a><br><br/>" \; >> ./index.html
    - echo "</body></html>" >> ./index.html
  when: always
  only:
    - dev
#Cache is required so that we have the report folder created from each pipeline. This allows us to list the files in the index html. 
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
      - public
#Artifact of each pipeline. Contains report of that particular pipeline. 
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_ID"
    expire_in: 1 day
    when: always
    paths:
      - public
```

Comment: Can you share your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? We could better help you if we could see it.

Comment: @Adam updated with a yml file

Comment: You have "expire_in: 1 day" set, so Gitlab will only keep the artifacts of the latest pipeline for longer than that (forever). So if you are trying to compare jobs older than that, this will not work...?