# Pass data between Gitlab pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pages

I need to pass the folders generated in one pipeline to the next pipeline in Gitlab CI. What are the possible ways?

1. Is it possible through just Artifacts?
2. Can we only achieve it through cache?
3. If by Cache, is there any expiry that we can set in cache?

My actual question was (but no answers so far) :
[Carry artifacts of Gitlab pages between pipelines/jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65733036/carry-artifacts-of-gitlab-pages-between-pipelines-jobs)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple distinction:

- **Cache** is used between multiple runs of **the same job in different pipelines** and also on the **same runner** (unless you have configured a shared cache storage)
- **Artifacts** are used to pass files between **different jobs within a single pipeline**

Jobs may specify an `artifacts:expire_in` keyword to control the lifespan of their artifacts (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifactsexpire_in ).